# How to only plot a chart when both x and y cells are not blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have data like this:

A    B    C    D
7    3    2
5         3    3

Cell A is X coordinates for chart1 and cell B is Y coordinates for chart1

Cell C is X coordinates for chart2 and cell D is Y coordinates for chart2

Some of the B cells and some of the D cells contain blank cells. I need to create chart1 and chart2 based on that data.

If I filter out on column B when there is a blank cell then that would also remove rows where there WAS a non-blank column D cell and vice versa.

Is there a way in Excel that I could filter maybe at the chart creation side for the individual charts to filter out blank B for chart1 and blank D for chart2?

Comment: You need to use `NA()` for those blank cells. Using some helper columns.

Comment: Refer this may help. **[Not Blank](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4374-excel-skip-blanks-in-chart.html#:~:text=Skip%20Blank%20Cells%20in%20Excel%201%201.%20After,screenshot%3A%20Then%20the%20blank%20cells%20...%20See%20More.)**

Comment: Which version of Excel and what type of chart?